# the_content(); of custom post type treated as an array or object

Tags: custom-post-types, pages, the-content

I created a custom post type in the mu-plugins folder.

```
function wpdocs_codex_book_init() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => _x( 'Books', 'Post type general name', 'textdomain' ),
        'singular_name'         => _x( 'book', 'Post type singular name', 'textdomain' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'             => $labels,
        'public'             => true,
    );

    register_post_type( 'book', $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'wpdocs_codex_book_init' );
```

When it comes to render the content of it in the single-book.php page I create the custom query and I use this code:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'book',
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
?>

<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<h1><?php the_content(); ?></h1>
```

the title is rendered correctly but when it comes to the content it throws this error:

> Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that
>   implements Countable in /app/public/wp-includes/post-template.php on
>   line 284

The default posts and the pages are, instead, rendered correctly. Why is this happening? Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you creating a new query in the template? Does it work correctly if you remove your query code?

Comment: totally my bad. Wordpress has already identified the correct query since i created the single-book itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`single-book.php` should not have a custom query in it. WordPress has already queried the correct post, so `new WP_Query( $args )` is completely unnecessary.

Your problem is that you're missing [the loop](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/).

At the bare minimum `single-book.php` should have:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

    <?php the_content(); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Definitely working. My concern was that using the loop every title and content of every book-post would have displayed, but that is is because the custom query was totally unnecessary.

Comment: The loop doesn't loop over every post. It loops over every post _in the main query_. The main query is run by WordPress and what it contains is determined by the current URL. On a single post it will only include the current post being views. On category archives it will only include the current page's worth of posts in the current category. Only use `WP_Query` if you intend to query for posts other than the ones that WordPress has already queried.